# How to get nested viewpager to intercept all swipes so the parent view pager won't swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a parent `ViewPager` that contains a `RecyclerView` on one of the tabs. The `RecyclerView` contains two types of items: an `ImageView` and a `ViewPager`. I want to keep the parent `ViewPager` swipeable unless the user tries to swipe on one of the `ViewPager` inside the `RecyclerView`. When the user tries the swipe the last item in nested `ViewPager`, I don't want the parent `ViewPager` to swipe.

How should i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding the solution:

```
public class ChildViewPager extends ViewPager {

public ChildViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public ChildViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Basically just have `canScrollHorizontally()` always return true